# Passing user specifications as arguments to dplyr within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm writing a new Shiny app, and I would like to stay within the Hadleyverse by using dplyr commands for data manipulation. I want Shiny to print a table showing only the top 3 observations according to a variable that can be chosen by the user. For example, one user may want to see the top 3 employees in terms of number of awards received, while another will want to see the top 3 in terms of number of award points earned.

In my latest attempt, I have this for ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
verticalLayout(
tableOutput("tbl"),
selectInput("top3", label = h4("Quantity"), 
  choices = list("Number of awards" = "NumberOfAwards", 
  "Total points awarded" = "TotalAwarded")), 
tableOutput("t3")
)))
```

and this for server.R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
employeestats <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
Employee  NumberOfAwards TotalAwarded
Al        3              10
Betty     6              20
Chuck     2              5
Donna     4              15
Ed        0              0
')  
output$tbl <- renderTable({ 
employeestats
},include.rownames=TRUE) 
datasetInput <- reactive({employeestats})
output$t3 <- renderTable({ 
head(datasetInput() %>% arrange(desc(input$top3)),n=3)  
},include.rownames=TRUE)
})
```

Outside of Shiny, the command

```
head(employeestats %>% arrange(desc(NumberOfAwards)),n=3)
```

gives the answer that I want for the top 3 award winners. In Shiny, the full table and the selection box are printed without the Top 3 table, and I get the message "Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : cannot arrange column of class 'NULL'". I know that this has something to do with both Shiny and dplyr using nonstandard functions, and that it could make a difference if R sees NumberOfAwards or the character string "NumberOfAwards". I've tried things like deparse(substitute()), using numbers to indicate the columns to arrange by, etc. without success. This doesn't have to be elaborate; for example, I don't care about ties for 3rd place.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `arrange()` function expects your argument as a `symbol`. 
However, your `input$top3` is a string.

The trick is:

```
output$t3 <- renderTable({ 
    sorted_stats <- eval(substitute(employeestats %>% arrange(desc(col)), 
                         list(col=as.symbol(input$top3))))
    head(sorted_stats,n=3)  
  },include.rownames=TRUE)
```

You can use `?substitute` to see how it works.

Short version, it parse the expression:

```
employeestats %>% arrange(desc(col))
```

into a parse tree consisting of `call`'s (functions) and `name`'s (symbols, constants, objects), allowing us to substitute the components to form a new expression.

To this point, the expression is not evaluated (meaning, the `employeestats` is not `arrange`d yet).

Here `col` doesn't really mean anything. It simply serves as a placeholder.
And by passing `list(col=as.symbol(input$top3))` to `substitute`, we replace the dummy symbol `col` by the actual symbol we would like to arrange by, `as.symbol(input$top3)`.
Depending on the current input, this would either be `TotalAwarded` or `NumberOfAwards` (symbols, not strings anymore).

Finally, the `eval()` function evaluated the expression (with `col` replaced by the actual symbol), and returns the sorted `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, and I appreciate the thorough explanation as well.

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to look at arrange_ (see [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)). Really nice for in Shiny apps.

The 1st option does what you want. The 2nd is cleaner but not exactly what you are looking for. I guess the 3rd option would be ideal but desc_ is not a function. Might be a nice addition :)

```
input <- list()
input$top3 <- "mpg"

mtcars %>%
  arrange_(paste0("desc(",input$top3,")"))  %>%
  head(n=3)

mtcars %>%
  arrange_(input$top3)  %>%
  tail(n=3)

# desc_ is not a function (yet)
mtcars %>%
  arrange(desc_(input$top3)) %>%
  head(n=3)
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that you can pass a vector of multiple strings to the argument, whereas with the eval(substitute(...)) solution relying on the as.symbol() function, you are limited to one user input factor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186374/group-by-dplyr-function-in-shiny and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688193/dplyrgroup-by-with-character-string-input-of-several-variable-names