# dplyr::group_by_ with character string input of several variable names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing a function where the user is asked to define one or more grouping variables in the function call. The data is then grouped using dplyr and it works as expected if there is only one grouping variable, but I haven't figured out how to do it with multiple grouping variables.

Example:

```
x <- c("cyl")
y <- c("cyl", "gear")
dots <- list(~cyl, ~gear)

library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval) 

mtcars %>% group_by_(x)             # groups by cyl
mtcars %>% group_by_(y)             # groups only by cyl (not gear)
mtcars %>% group_by_(.dots = dots)  # groups by cyl and gear, this is what I want.
```

I tried to turn `y` into the same as `dots` using:

```
mtcars %>% group_by_(.dots = interp(~var, var = list(y)))
#Error: is.call(expr) || is.name(expr) || is.atomic(expr) is not TRUE
```

How to use a user-defined input string of > 1 variable names (like `y` in the example) to group the data using dplyr?

(This question is somehow related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-on-variable-given-as-a-character-string) but not answered there.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No need for `interp` here, just use `as.formula` to convert the strings to formulas:

```
dots = sapply(y, . %>% {as.formula(paste0('~', .))})
mtcars %>% group_by_(.dots = dots)
```

The reason why your `interp` approach doesn’t work is that the expression gives you back the following:

```
~list(c("cyl", "gear"))
```

– not what you want. You could, of course, `sapply` `interp` over `y`, which would be similar to using `as.formula` above:

```
dots1 = sapply(y, . %>% {interp(~var, var = .)})
```

**But, in fact, you can also directly pass `y`:**

```
mtcars %>% group_by_(.dots = y)
```

The [dplyr vignette on non-standard evaluation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) goes into more detail and explains the difference between these approaches.

Comment: @David I wouldn’t use it. I’m just showing it to answer OP’s direct question of how to convert a character vector into a vector of formulas. That said, there *is* a difference (the formulas come with an environment attached), and in general the dplyr documentation recommends using formulas over character strings. However, in this particular case the environment is a bit useless.

Comment: Thanks so much for this write-up, @Konrad-Rudolph. It saved me a lot of pain. I'm having trouble understanding your sapply function... what are the "." in it?

Comment: `group_by_` is now deprecated; you can now use `group_by_at(vars(...))`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954739/1193577) to a related question (note that the call to `one_of()` in that answer may be unnecessary).

Answer (score 2):

`slice_rows()` from the `purrrlyr` package (https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr) groups a `data.frame` by taking a vector of column names (strings) or positions (integers):

```
y <- c("cyl", "gear")
mtcars_grp <- mtcars %>% purrrlyr::slice_rows(y)

class(mtcars_grp)
#> [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

group_vars(mtcars_grp)
#> [1] "cyl"  "gear"
```

Particularly useful now that `group_by_()` has been depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like one of these is what you want:

```r
# one variable (as a string):
mtcars %>% group_by(.data[[x]])            # groups by cyl
# OR
mtcars %>% group_by(across(all_of(x)))     # groups by cyl

# multiple: 
mtcars %>% group_by(across(all_of(y)))     # groups cyl, gear
```

See: [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)