# How can I pass a vector as variable arguments into a function in R

Tags: r

I am not sure if what i am trying to do makes sense in R.

I want to do the something like follow:

```
fun <- function(df, args){
    .....
    df %>%
    group_by(args)
    .....
```

I am trying to pass a char vector as args, then group by the args as column name, but it does not work.

i have tried *get* and *mget*, they do not work the way i want.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688193/dplyrgroup-by-with-character-string-input-of-several-variable-names i.e. use `group_by_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small example of how to accomplish that.  You pass in a string of args, we use `syms` from `rlang` to turn that into a list of symbols.  We then use the `!!!` unquote-splice operator to group by those symbols.

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(df, args){

  by <- syms(args)

   df %>%
     group_by(!!!by) %>% 
     summarize_all(mean)
  }
```

Using this example with `mtcars`:

```
> fun(mtcars, c("cyl"))
# A tibble: 3 x 11
    cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  4.00  26.7   105  82.6  4.07  2.29  19.1 0.909 0.727  4.09  1.55
2  6.00  19.7   183 122    3.59  3.12  18.0 0.571 0.429  3.86  3.43
3  8.00  15.1   353 209    3.23  4.00  16.8 0     0.143  3.29  3.50
```

Comment: You do not need  `rlang` anymore  just `!!by` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Comment: `syms` isn't exported by `dplyr`.  OP requested input as a character vector, so `rlang` is required.