# Convert multiple strings into object references

Tags: r

Is it possible to dynamically convert strings into object references? Suppose we have:

```
a <- 5
b <- 6

letters <- c("a", "b")
```

`eval(parse(text = "a"))` returns the value for `a`, or `5`. Is it possible to have the values for multiple strings returned? When I include multiple strings in `parse` only the last value is returned.

```
>eval(parse(text = letters))
[1] 6
```

The desired output is a vector or values for the inputted strings:

```
[1] 5 6
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate; there are several existing questions on using `mget()` with vectors of strings, including with [dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013141/how-can-i-pass-a-vector-as-variable-arguments-into-a-function-in-r) and [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584346/supply-arguments-to-data-table-as-1-vector-of-strings-and-2-variablenames). Ultimately your intent is to parameterize which objects you pass into function calls, right? It is possible to avoid writing this sort of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parametrize function calls in dplyr 0.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415475/how-to-parametrize-function-calls-in-dplyr-0-7)

Comment: Generally noone should ever need to write code like this, any time you find yourself doing it it's a code smell you're not using your library right. Based on your other questions it seems like you're constructing calls to dplyr for Shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can use `mget` to return the values of the objects in a `list` and then `unlist` the `list` output

```
unlist(mget(letters), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 5 6
```

---

Also, if we are using `eval(parse`, it works only for a single element, so loop through the 'letters' and then do `eval(parse`

```
unname(sapply(letters, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
#[1] 5 6
```

However, the recommended option would be `mget`

---

`letters/LETTERS` are inbuilt `Constants` to return the lower/upper case letters.  So, it is better not to use identifier names with reserve words or function names